# Same birthday for two people with and without replacement

Tags: probability, independence, birthday

It is known that for choosing 2 people out of n with birthdays A,B the probability that A=B is $\frac{1}{365}$. In this case we have replacement which means that we may choose the same person twice. A and B are of course independent. What I need to understand is the case where we choose two different people without replacement. Let's assume that X,Y are their birthdays, then Y is dependent of X (right?). What is the probability that X=Y?

Comment: The case where you choose different people (without replacement) is the case where it is $\frac{1}{365}$. Choosing two people with replacement always has at least $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of picking the same person twice, so those always have the same birthday. So the probability with replacement is $$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{1}{365}=\frac{n+364}{365n}$$

Comment: In the comment of @ThomasAndrews it is used that the probability that $2$ different persons have the same birthday is $\frac1{365}$. This is the answer to your second question concerning "without replacement". There is indeed independence there.